# bat - файл, скрипт

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Всем привет!
 А подскажите скрипт для bat файла, чтобы запустить консоль cmd и выполнить в ней нужную команду?
**Нужно сделать:**
Создать bat - файл, который в свою очередь запустит еще 3 bat - файла, но запустить их нужно с правами разных пользователей, т.е нужно в батник как то положить команду runas.
Хотелось бы увидеть мини примеры, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это прям какое-то масло масляное... `start` создаёт новый CMD-процесс.

Comment: Дело в том, что нужно создать bat - файл, который в свою очередь запустит еще 3 bat - файла, но запустить их нужно с правами разных пользователей, т.е нужно в батник как то положить команду runas

Comment: *нужно в батник как то положить команду runas* Ну и положите... либо просто runas, если их нужно выполнять последовательно, либо start "" runas, если параллельно. Я что-то не вижу, в чём тут проблема-то...

Comment: если честно, с ними первый раз столкнулся, запустить нужно параллельно, я правильно понимаю start "(скрипт cmd)" runas (параметры)

Comment: внесите, пожалуйста, ту информацию, что вы привели в комментарии, непосредственно в текст вопроса (нажав [edit])

Comment: `start` запускает новый CMD-процесс с указанной командой и (без ключа `/w`) сразу возвращает управление в текущий батч. См. справку, `start /?`.

Comment: Если Вы используете запуск скриптов от разных пользователей, то я настоятельно рекомендовал бы изучить синтаксис консольной утилиты [schtasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248001/). С её помощью или соответствующей оснастки "Планировщик" можно создать задания на запуск. Также следует дать пользователю права на старт заданий, либо прописать соответствующие триггеры у задания. Пример вызова задания с консоли: **schtasks /run /tn "Task 1"**.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте файл с расширением .bat, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Внесите в него текст скрипта:

```
@echo off
title This is your first batch script!
echo Welcome to batch scripting!
pause
```

Результат:
[image: Результат:]